# agora_rtc_engine implementation for video and voice call within a chat module

Tags: video, flutter-dependencies, call, voice, agora-implementation

- What went wrong:

  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/home/cenit/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtc_engine-6.2.6/android/.cxx/Debug/4w1r2t6s/arm64-v8a'
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/iris_rendering_android.dir/iris_rtc_rendering_android.cc.o
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/iris_rendering_android.dir/iris_rtc_rendering_android.cc.o
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  /home/cenit/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/cenit/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/cenit/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Diris_rendering_android_EXPORTS -I/home/cenit/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtc_engine-6.2.6/android/src/main/cpp/third_party/include/iris -I/home/cenit/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtc_engine-6.2.6/android/src/main/cpp/third_party/include/agora_rtc -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/iris_rendering_android.dir/iris_rtc_rendering_android.cc.o -MF CMakeFiles/iris_rendering_android.dir/iris_rtc_rendering_android.cc.o.d -o CMakeFiles/iris_rendering_android.dir/iris_rtc_rendering_android.cc.o -c /home/cenit/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtc_engine-6.2.6/android/src/main/cpp/iris_rtc_rendering_android.cc
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  In file included from /home/cenit/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtc_engine-6.2.6/android/src/main/cpp/iris_rtc_rendering_android.cc:13:
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  /snap/flutter/current/usr/include/c++/9/memory:121:25: error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'uintptr_t' (aka 'unsigned int') loses information
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  const auto __intptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(__ptr);
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  1 error generated.
  Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

I tried upgrading the miniSdkVersion to 21, made sure I added camera and voice permissions to my AndroidManifest.xml, I also made sure the dependencies were installed in pubspec.yaml file.

I expected to have the app successfully run on my mobile phone while signaling that a remote user is awaited to join call.